# What code wiill run in Dartium if both Dart and JS files are linked in the page?

Tags: javascript, dart

I have a link to dart source file to develop and debug my app and a link to JS bundle file for production.

I think about putting them together like this:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="app.dart"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I suppose regular browsers will ignore first link and use second one.
But, which of them will run in Dartium?

Should I put them together at all or should I put dart for development and js in the release dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way is to have these tags in your page:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="app.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

The dart.js file is used to check for native Dart support and either download the Dart script or load compiled JS. See this page for more info: https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/browser/0.10.0%2B2/

When you build your app for deployment you should replace the 2 tags with the Javascript version.

```
<script src="app.dart.js"></script>
```

You could do this automatically with the `dart_to_js_script_rewriter` transformer.
See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter

For this to work, you should have this in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: any
transformers:
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```